# All packages of golang testify not getting download

Tags: go, testify

Am trying to download all testify packages of `Golang`. I am running `go get github.com/stretchr/testify`. After that if I run `go mod vendor` only assert package is getting download. I need other packages too, like `suite`, `mock` but for some reason not getting those. Not able to get what is the reason. Also am using `VSCode` for development and using `VSCode` terminal to download the packages. I didn't face the same for other packages.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your code you are using only `assert` functionality.
Most packages in testify are independent, and they don't call any other packages internally.

Lets say for example, if `assert` package had a function that was calling other function from `mock` package. Then both of them would be vendored.

If you want to use any other package, just import it with:

```
import (
   ...
  "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)
```

And again do:

```
go mod vendor
```

Comment: Initially I was using only assert package. But now I want to use suite also, how will I do that then? Please let me know.